# Combining R shiny checkboxGroupInput with other input selections

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I have these `data` I want to `scatter` `plot` using an `R` `shiny` server:

```
library(dplyr)
library(permute)
set.seed(1)

meta.df <- data.frame(gene_id=paste0("id",1:10),symbol=paste0("n",rep(permute::shuffle(5),2)),stringsAsFactors=F)
clusters.df <- data.frame(cell=paste0("c",1:100),cluster=rep(permute::shuffle(10),10),sample=paste0("s",rep(permute::shuffle(5),20)),stringsAsFactors=F)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(10*100),10,100,dimnames=list(meta.df$gene_id,clusters.df$cell))
tsne.obj <- Rtsne::Rtsne(t(mat))
tsne.df <- as.data.frame(tsne.obj$Y) %>% dplyr::rename(tSNE1=V1,tSNE2=V2) %>% cbind(clusters.df)
samples <- c("all",unique(clusters.df$sample))
samples.choices <- 1:length(samples)
names(samples.choices) <- samples
```

Since I want to be able to select a specific `meta.df$symbol`, which is redundant within `meta.df$gene_id`, each has a selection list, where the second is conditioned on the first.

Since the data are comprised of several `sample`s, I'd like to be able to subset the data by `sample` in a reactive way, hence I have a sample choice `checkbox`, with the `"all"` option that selects all `sample`s (just coz it's easier than checking all boxes).

So here's my `shiny` `code`:

```
server <- function(input, output)
{
  chosen.samples <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$samples.choice != "",'Please choose at least one of the sample checkboxes')
    )
    samples.choice <- input$samples.choice
    if("all" %in% samples.choice) samples.choice <- samples[-which(samples == "all")]
    samples.choice
  })

  output$gene_id <- renderUI({
    selectInput("gene_id", "Gene ID", choices = unique(dplyr::filter(meta.df,symbol == input$symbol)$gene_id))
  })

  scatter.plot <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$symbol) & !is.null(input$gene_id)){
      # subset of data
      gene.symbol <- input$symbol
      gene.id <- input$gene_id
      row.idx <- which(rownames(mat) == gene.id)
      col.idx <- which(colnames(mat) %in% dplyr::filter(clusters.df,sample %in% chosen.samples())$cell)
      gene.df <- suppressWarnings(dplyr::left_join(tsne.df %>% dplyr::filter(sample %in% chosen.samples()),data.frame(cell=colnames(mat)[col.idx],value=mat[row.idx,col.idx],stringsAsFactors=F),by=c("cell"="cell")))
      scatter.plot <- plotly::plot_ly(marker=list(size=12),type='scatter',mode="markers",color=~gene.df$value,x=~gene.df$tSNE1,y=~gene.df$tSNE2,showlegend=F) %>%
        plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title="tSNE1",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),yaxis=list(title="tSNE2",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F))
      scatter.plot
    }
  })

  output$Embedding <- renderPlot({
    scatter.plot()
  })

  output$save <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0(dplyr::filter(meta.df,symbol == input$symbol,gene_id == input$gene_id)$symbol,"_",dplyr::filter(meta.df,symbol == input$symbol,gene_id == input$gene_id)$gene_id,".pdf")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      plotly::export(scatter.plot(),file=file)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Results Explorer"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # select samples
      checkboxGroupInput("samples.choice", "Samples",choices = samples.choices,selected=1),

      # select gene symbol
      selectInput("symbol", "Gene Symbol", choices = unique(meta.df$symbol)),

      # select gene id
      uiOutput("gene_id"),

      # select plot type
      selectInput("plot.type", "Plot Type", choices = c("tSNE","PCA")),

      # save plot as html
      downloadButton('save', 'Save as PDF')
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # The plot is called Embedding and will be created in ShinyServer part
      plotOutput("Embedding")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to actually select the `sample`s, and hence the plot that is displayed has no points.

It works find if I simply eliminate the `sample`s selection `code` by replacing:

```
col.idx <- which(colnames(mat) %in% dplyr::filter(clusters.df,sample %in% chosen.samples())$cell)
gene.df <- suppressWarnings(dplyr::left_join(tsne.df %>% dplyr::filter(sample %in% chosen.samples()),data.frame(cell=colnames(mat)[col.idx],value=mat[row.idx,col.idx],stringsAsFactors=F),by=c("cell"="cell")))
```

with:

```
col.idx <- which(colnames(mat) %in% dplyr::filter(clusters.df,sample %in% samples[2:3])$cell)
gene.df <- dplyr::left_join(tsne.df %>% dplyr::filter(sample %in% samples[2:3]),data.frame(cell=colnames(mat)[col.idx],value=mat[row.idx,col.idx],stringsAsFactors=F),by=c("cell"="cell"))
```

I see that in [this example](https://blog.karawoo.com/2015/02/18/interactively-visualizing-my-cars-gas-mileage-with-shiny) the entire data are subsetted in the `dat_reac` `reactive` `block`. I'd expect simply getting the `sample`s to subset by would be enough. Any idea why it doesn't work and how to get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code. The first one is in `checkboxGroupInput`

Instead of

```
checkboxGroupInput("samples.choice", "Samples",choices = samples.choices,selected=1)
```

it should be

```
checkboxGroupInput("samples.choice", "Samples",choices = names(samples.choices),selected="all")
```

The second is `scatter.plot()` is `plotly object` hence you should use `plotly::plotlyOutput("Embedding")` and `output$Embedding <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    scatter.plot()
  })`

Here is the code with above modification which should work:

```
server <- function(input, output)
{
  chosen.samples <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$samples.choice != "",'Please choose at least one of the sample checkboxes')
    )
    samples.choice <- input$samples.choice
    if("all" %in% samples.choice) samples.choice <- samples[-which(samples == "all")]
    samples.choice
  })

  output$gene_id <- renderUI({
    selectInput("gene_id", "Gene ID", choices = unique(dplyr::filter(meta.df,symbol == input$symbol)$gene_id))
  })

  scatter.plot <- reactive({

    if(!is.null(input$symbol) & !is.null(input$gene_id)){
      # subset of data
      gene.symbol <- input$symbol
      gene.id <- input$gene_id
      row.idx <- which(rownames(mat) == gene.id)
      col.idx <- which(colnames(mat) %in% dplyr::filter(clusters.df,sample %in% chosen.samples())$cell)
      gene.df <- suppressWarnings(dplyr::left_join(tsne.df %>% dplyr::filter(sample %in% chosen.samples()),data.frame(cell=colnames(mat)[col.idx],value=mat[row.idx,col.idx],stringsAsFactors=F),by=c("cell"="cell")))

      scatter.plot <- plotly::plot_ly(marker=list(size=12),type='scatter',mode="markers",color=~gene.df$value,x=~gene.df$tSNE1,y=~gene.df$tSNE2,showlegend=F) %>%
        plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title="tSNE1",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F),yaxis=list(title="tSNE2",zeroline=F,showticklabels=F))
      scatter.plot
    }
  })

  output$Embedding <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    scatter.plot()
  })

  output$save <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0(dplyr::filter(meta.df,symbol == input$symbol,gene_id == input$gene_id)$symbol,"_",dplyr::filter(meta.df,symbol == input$symbol,gene_id == input$gene_id)$gene_id,".pdf")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      plotly::export(scatter.plot(),file=file)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Results Explorer"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # select samples
      checkboxGroupInput("samples.choice", "Samples",choices = names(samples.choices),selected="all"),

      # select gene symbol
      selectInput("symbol", "Gene Symbol", choices = unique(meta.df$symbol)),

      # select gene id
      uiOutput("gene_id"),

      # select plot type
      selectInput("plot.type", "Plot Type", choices = c("tSNE","PCA")),

      # save plot as html
      downloadButton('save', 'Save as PDF')
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # The plot is called Embedding and will be created in ShinyServer part
      # plotOutput("Embedding")
      plotly::plotlyOutput("Embedding")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @SBista. I have a couple of more questions you might happen to easily help me out with: 1. if I launch the shiny app from my terminal window, it opens in my browser and the plot is only displayed over the top right quadrant of the page. Is it possible to expand it? 2. When I press the "save" button the resulting PDF includes two pages where the second one is blank. Is there a way to prevent this? Meaning to save only one page?

Comment: @dan,what do you mean by expand? Its taking the available width.

Comment: I meant the vertical space